# i cant understand this bit-manipulation python code

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, reverse-engineering, reverse, bit-shift

i see alot of code patterns in Reverse Engineering writeups and i don't understand it like this one
`(some_value >> 8) & 0xff`
can anyone explain it?

Comment: This expression doesn't care/doesn't say anything about the registers. It's just a simple bitshift / bitwise-and operation on an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to understand things on a registers level. Just think of the `int` as an `int`.

What happens when you take an int like, say, `0x12345678` and shift it right 8 bits?

Well, let's see:

```
>>> hex(0x12345678 >> 8)
'0x123456'
```

You've knocked off the two rightmost digits—that is, the rightmost byte—because a byte is 8 bits.

Now what happens if you bitwise-and it with `0xff`?

```
>>> hex(0x123456 & 0xff)
'0x56'
```

You've knocked off everything *except* the two rightmost digits—that is, everything but the last byte—because `0xff` is a byte full of `1` bits.

Put it together:

```
>>> hex((0x12345678 >> 8) & 0xff)
'0x56'
```

So you're getting the next to last byte.

And you can extract each byte of an int this way:

```
>>> hex((0x12345678 >> 0) & 0xff)
'0x78'
>>> hex((0x12345678 >> 8) & 0xff)
'0x56'
>>> hex((0x12345678 >> 16) & 0xff)
'0x34'
>>> hex((0x12345678 >> 24) & 0xff)
'0x12'
>>> hex((0x12345678 >> 32) & 0xff)
'0x00'
```

Comment: Thanks alot ! finally I can understand it